# Book cover-art: Desert with mesas and a city-ship on top

Tags: cover-art

I remember seeing a sci-fi book cover back in about 1980/81 at my public library that was likely based upon an earlier painting.  It depicted an arid desert scene with the landscape dominated by a group of mesas in the distance. The nearest mesa had a gleaming city-ship atop it.  In the distance you could see an identical city-ship just arising from another mesa.

I remember thinking that this was an awesome painting and I wish I could locate what the title of the painting was and its artist, if at all possible.  I would love to see this painting again, but I never have.

Comment: Sounds like something you could see on the cover of Dune. Does [any of this](https://www.google.com/search?q=dune+cover+art&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D0&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=J5gsUYKBF7KM4gSbmIGwCA&biw=1092&bih=526&sei=bZgsUeGfBqGl4ASKjoCIDA) ring a bell?

Comment: Sounds very "Cities in Flight"-esque to me, but I'm not able to find anything that matches the description.

Comment: Do you remember how old the book was? Paperback or hardback? Do you remember anything about the content of the book?

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing sounds very like the painting ["The Thrall of Hypno"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1519663) by Angus McKie most famously published as "City Ships of Alpha" in
[*Spacecraft 2000 to 2100 AD: Terran Trade Authority Handbook*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?273436) by Stewart Cowley.

[image: City Ships of Alpha by Angus McKie]

The image was originally painted as a cover for [*The Thrall of Hypno (Perry Rhodan #20)*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?314724) and also used for [*The Complete Science Fiction Treasury of H.G. Wells*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?268108) [among others](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1519663).

Comment: Looking through the cover images for books by [Stewart Cowley](http://www.librarything.com/author/cowleystewart&all=1) on LibraryThing doesn't reveal anything like the image the OP described. The closest is a cover where there are ships landing/taking off from some burning high-rise buildings.

Comment: The book is presented as a spacecraft recognition guide so contains many pictures that may have not made it too book covers. The city ships themselves can be seen in a picture at http://www.bisbos.com/sf_tta_u_cityships.html

Answer (score 2):

This is the book cover I believe you are referring to. Artwork is by Angus McKie and does indeed feature in Stewart Cowley's *Spacecraft 2000 to 2100 AD*.

[image: The Thrall of Hypno (Perry Rhodan #20) Cover]

Answer (score 1):

Could it have been the cover of Clifford D. Simak's [*Time and Again*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?267980)?

[image: Cover of "Time and Again" by Clifford Simak]